# Choosing compression algorithm with highest compression ratio

Tags: javascript, algorithm, browser, compression, lossless-compression

I'm looking for a compression algorithm that:

- must be loseless
- must have very high compression ratio
- must be supported in browser via JavaScript libs or natively
- shouldn't be fast.

Goals:

1. to compress dense array of 8 million double-precision floats. There only 256 unique values. Values are normally distributed. (primary use-case)
2. the same as before but for sparse arrays (contains a lot of 0 values)

It' OK for me to use 2 different algorithms for these use-cases.

I've found Google's [Brotli](https://github.com/google/brotli) algorithm. But I'm not sure if it is the best.

Comment: SO is not Google.

Comment: `shouldn't be fast` now *that*'s an unusual requirement: care to elaborate?

Comment: Why do you expect the dense array of floats to be compressible? If there is some pattern or redundancy in there, then you will begin to get some sort of answer on how to model the data to enable compression.

Comment: @MarkAdler It appears that I can encode the float number with just 1 byte. That was the redundancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've a lot of float numbers. But because there are only 256 unique values I can encode each number as 1 byte. It gives a huge compression ratio.
After that I can run some general purpose algorithm for further data compression.
I've checked several popular algorithms: gzip, Brotli, bzip2, lzma, Zstandard.

I've found that 2 options suit my needs:

- bzip2
- Brotli

**bzip2**:

- compresses well even if I don't convert the floats to unsigned bytes.
- but requires JS library in browser

**Brotli**:

- compresses well only if I manually map all floats to unsigned bytes before
- supported natively by nearly all modern browsers

Comment: This seems to call for a rewording in the question: *compress big (huge? large? If possible, give a distribution/range of size) arrays of float numbers from a domain 256 distinct values known to the decompressor 1) primary use-case: dense arrays 2) minor use-case: sparse arrays*.

Comment: @greybeard I've found that values are normally distributed.

Comment: *`values`* `are normally distributed` - great, but lacking *mean* and *variance*. Then, I asked about the *array size*, not the values.

Answer (score 3):

Coding is pretty much a problem solved: your main task will be *modelling* (starting with `float number` and `lossless`).
`[primarily dense arrays] of 256 unique float numbers` doesn't sound promising: depending on range, exponent representation may be the only source of exploitable redundancy.
`sparse array` *does* sound promising, 16×16 sparse matrix even more so. The more you know about your data, the more you can help compressors - "mainly diagonal matrix", anyone?

"General purpose data compressors" exploit self-similarity:
To get an idea where your data has such, use "the usual suspects" on whatever "machine representation" you chose and on a generic unicode representation.
The latter allows you to use no more resolution than required.

Comment: Thanks. I have just understood that my pattern is that each float number can just be mapped to byte. After that some "general purpose" can be run.